# How to deploy a Python/Django app on Heroku that connects to an Oracle Cloud Database?

Tags: python, heroku, django-database, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

When I go to deploy my Python Django app to Heroku. I get the following error/build log output.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.11.2
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.11.2
-----> Installing pip 23.0.1, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.38.4
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting asgiref==3.6.0
         Downloading asgiref-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
       Collecting astroid==2.15.0
         Downloading astroid-2.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (277 kB)
       Collecting certifi==2022.12.7
         Downloading certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
       Collecting cffi==1.15.1
         Downloading cffi-1.15.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (462 kB)
       Collecting channels==3.0.4
         Downloading channels-3.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
       Collecting charset-normalizer==3.1.0
         Downloading charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (197 kB)
       Collecting config==0.5.1
         Downloading config-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
       Collecting cryptography==39.0.2
         Downloading cryptography-39.0.2-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
       Collecting cx-Oracle==8.3.0
         Downloading cx_Oracle-8.3.0.tar.gz (363 kB)
         Installing build dependencies: started
         Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
         Getting requirements to build wheel: started
         Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting defusedxml==0.7.1
         Downloading defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
       Collecting dill==0.3.6
         Downloading dill-0.3.6-py3-none-any.whl (110 kB)
       Collecting Django==4.1.7
         Downloading Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
       Collecting django-allauth==0.52.0
         Downloading django-allauth-0.52.0.tar.gz (728 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting django-environ==0.10.0
         Downloading django_environ-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting django-widget-tweaks==1.4.12
         Downloading django_widget_tweaks-1.4.12-py3-none-any.whl (8.9 kB)
       Collecting humanfriendly==10.0
         Downloading humanfriendly-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
       Collecting idna==3.4
         Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
       Collecting isort==5.12.0
         Downloading isort-5.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
       Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.9.0
         Downloading lazy_object_proxy-1.9.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (64 kB)
       Collecting mccabe==0.7.0
         Downloading mccabe-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.3 kB)
       Collecting oauthlib==3.2.2
         Downloading oauthlib-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (151 kB)
       Collecting oracledb==1.2.2
         Downloading oracledb-1.2.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (8.0 MB)
       Collecting platformdirs==3.1.1
         Downloading platformdirs-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
       Collecting pycparser==2.21
         Downloading pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
       Collecting PyJWT==2.6.0
         Downloading PyJWT-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
       Collecting pylint==2.17.0
         Downloading pylint-2.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (535 kB)
       Collecting pylint-django==2.5.3
         Downloading pylint_django-2.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (81 kB)
       Collecting pylint-plugin-utils==0.7
         Downloading pylint_plugin_utils-0.7-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
       Collecting python-dotenv==1.0.0
         Downloading python_dotenv-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
       Collecting python-environ==0.4.54
         Downloading python-environ-0.4.54.tar.gz (22 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting python3-openid==3.2.0
         Downloading python3_openid-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
       Collecting requests==2.28.2
         Downloading requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
       Collecting requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
         Downloading requests_oauthlib-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
       Collecting sqlparse==0.4.3
         Downloading sqlparse-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
       Collecting tomlkit==0.11.6
         Downloading tomlkit-0.11.6-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
       Collecting urllib3==1.26.14
         Downloading urllib3-1.26.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
       Collecting wrapt==1.15.0
         Downloading wrapt-1.15.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (78 kB)
       Collecting daphne<4,>=3.0
         Downloading daphne-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
       Collecting twisted[tls]>=18.7
         Downloading Twisted-22.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 MB)
       Collecting autobahn>=0.18
         Downloading autobahn-23.1.2.tar.gz (480 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting txaio>=21.2.1
         Downloading txaio-23.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
       Collecting hyperlink>=21.0.0
         Downloading hyperlink-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
       Collecting zope.interface>=4.4.2
         Downloading zope.interface-6.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (249 kB)
       Collecting constantly>=15.1
         Downloading constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.9 kB)
       Collecting incremental>=21.3.0
         Downloading incremental-22.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting Automat>=0.8.0
         Downloading Automat-22.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
       Collecting attrs>=19.2.0
         Downloading attrs-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
       Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5
         Downloading typing_extensions-4.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
       Collecting pyopenssl>=21.0.0
         Downloading pyOpenSSL-23.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
       Collecting service-identity>=18.1.0
         Downloading service_identity-21.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
       Collecting six
         Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting pyasn1-modules
         Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
       Collecting pyasn1
         Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
       Building wheels for collected packages: cx-Oracle, django-allauth, python-environ, autobahn
         Building wheel for cx-Oracle (pyproject.toml): started
         Building wheel for cx-Oracle (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for cx-Oracle: filename=cx_Oracle-8.3.0-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl size=210943 sha256=45e8fd49b82fe4b86643fa8eb0a425d895b0f4b23ef7345407910610694b209d
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-73oja8kp/wheels/e0/41/f9/63e9c4d1ec7b2e8faffc1d6f3219c2e168c306b042d77e2b6f
         Building wheel for django-allauth (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for django-allauth (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for django-allauth: filename=django_allauth-0.52.0-py3-none-any.whl size=1063914 sha256=1155c2187de4e64fafe4dda0509fd28bd8d687bcb31330b5fe098121df7cf61c
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-73oja8kp/wheels/e1/c8/ca/7e4be574a46605642219627189c7a61527cedbf04f507b0b06
         Building wheel for python-environ (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for python-environ (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for python-environ: filename=python_environ-0.4.54-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=16341 sha256=4f10b16448a2c82a66813e4e6db5392335f28227c2bd645da32aeea559633242
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-73oja8kp/wheels/98/67/9a/de43dd9ce52d81c220f8382bde233435bd544e8145fc7e49e0
         Building wheel for autobahn (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for autobahn (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for autobahn: filename=autobahn-23.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=666855 sha256=b590e20ceaa791e68ddf732bea1289b5f7216e48cf20f362f66003490ae2c65d
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-73oja8kp/wheels/19/4b/71/60bf756ecc15f1aa77a8dd7aca9907d3599a565807c8d52fb7
       Successfully built cx-Oracle django-allauth python-environ autobahn
       Installing collected packages: python-environ, pyasn1, incremental, cx-Oracle, constantly, config, zope.interface, wrapt, urllib3, typing-extensions, txaio, tomlkit, sqlparse, six, python-dotenv, PyJWT, pycparser, pyasn1-modules, platformdirs, oauthlib, mccabe, lazy-object-proxy, isort, idna, humanfriendly, django-widget-tweaks, django-environ, dill, defusedxml, charset-normalizer, certifi, attrs, asgiref, requests, python3-openid, hyperlink, Django, cffi, Automat, astroid, twisted, requests-oauthlib, pylint, cryptography, service-identity, pyopenssl, pylint-plugin-utils, oracledb, autobahn, pylint-django, django-allauth, daphne, channels
       Successfully installed Automat-22.10.0 Django-4.1.7 PyJWT-2.6.0 asgiref-3.6.0 astroid-2.15.0 attrs-22.2.0 autobahn-23.1.2 certifi-2022.12.7 cffi-1.15.1 channels-3.0.4 charset-normalizer-3.1.0 config-0.5.1 constantly-15.1.0 cryptography-39.0.2 cx-Oracle-8.3.0 daphne-3.0.2 defusedxml-0.7.1 dill-0.3.6 django-allauth-0.52.0 django-environ-0.10.0 django-widget-tweaks-1.4.12 humanfriendly-10.0 hyperlink-21.0.0 idna-3.4 incremental-22.10.0 isort-5.12.0 lazy-object-proxy-1.9.0 mccabe-0.7.0 oauthlib-3.2.2 oracledb-1.2.2 platformdirs-3.1.1 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pycparser-2.21 pylint-2.17.0 pylint-django-2.5.3 pylint-plugin-utils-0.7 pyopenssl-23.1.1 python-dotenv-1.0.0 python-environ-0.4.54 python3-openid-3.2.0 requests-2.28.2 requests-oauthlib-1.3.1 service-identity-21.1.0 six-1.16.0 sqlparse-0.4.3 tomlkit-0.11.6 twisted-22.10.0 txaio-23.1.1 typing-extensions-4.5.0 urllib3-1.26.14 wrapt-1.15.0 zope.interface-6.0
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_63541e73/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "/tmp/build_63541e73/manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 386, in execute
           settings.INSTALLED_APPS
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
           self._setup(name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
           self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
           mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_63541e73/config/settings.py", line 20, in <module>
           oracledb.init_oracle_client(
         File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 455, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
         File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 479, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
         File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 400, in oracledb.thick_impl._raise_from_info
       oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en//latest/user_guide/initialization.html#setting-the-oracle-client-library-directory for help
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Obviously this is because the Oracle Instant Client libraries are not being deployed with the app.

My question is how do I modify my app so it is able to deploy on Heroku and be able to connect to my Oracle Cloud Database?

I will provide all required files, im just not sure what is required to resolve the issue atm.

Neither Oracle, nor Heroku seem to have adequate documentation to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try running python-oracledb in Thin mode, i.e. make sure there are no calls to `init_oracle_client()` in the app.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Tried in thin mode (call to init_oracle_client() were commented out) and received the following error.

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

Comment: You are installing python-oracledb and it's older version cx_Oracle.  Possibly you still have some cx_Oracle usage in the app stack somewhere.  [Upgrade it](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_c.html#upgrading-from-cx-oracle-8-3-to-python-oracledb) or [map the name](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_c.html#python-frameworks-sql-generators-and-orms).

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using the Heroku-22 stack which looks like it is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack

We recently constructed a django -> Oracle ADB docker container (on Oracle Linux 8) so had to install the following packages at container build time to get the db client working for our app:

```
oracle-instantclient-release-el8    
oracle-instantclient-basic     
oracle-instantclient-sqlplus
```

For OL8 we used:

```
dnf -y install oracle-instantclient-release-el8
```

We followed this doc for background info: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lacli/install-instant-client-using-rpm.html#GUID-2E81E2AE-E94C-413F-99B2-AE9A3949F05D

I would pick the relevant package manager for your stack and then try to get the above packages installed at build time.  If there isn't a compatible package manager then you might need to download the zips and install that way: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lacli/install-instant-client-using-zip.html#GUID-D3DCB4FB-D3CA-4C25-BE48-3A1FB5A22E84

In addition your settings.py file would need something like the following for the django app to init the connection:

```
import cx_Oracle
    
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client()
```